# MariaDB: inconsistent SELECT results involving JSON

Tags: mariadb, select, json, mariadb-10.6

When executing the following statments on MariaDB 10.6.14

```
SET @json_1 = JSON_OBJECT('id', 'name');
SET @json_result_1 = JSON_OBJECT('test', @json_1);
SELECT @json_result_1;
SET @json_result_2 = JSON_OBJECT('test', JSON_OBJECT('id', 'name'));
SELECT @json_result_2;
```

I receive the following results:

For `@json_result_1`:

```
{"test": "{\"id\": \"name\"}"}
```

And for `@json_result_2`:

```
{"test": {"id": "name"}}
```

How does it come that I retrieve different result? Aren't those JSON string supposed to be internally all treated as TEXT?

Comment: Still there in 10.6.16 - please [report a bug](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Comment: Thanks @danblack : https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32888

Answer (score 0):

So. After not even a day in the bug tracker for MariaDB I got the following back and the ticket was closed:

> It behaves as expected. MariaDB knows that the output of `JSON_OBJECT()` is a json. But when you store it in a variable, it loses its "json-ness" and becomes a literal string.

> To force a string to be interpreted as a json, you can use, indeed, `JSON_EXTRACT`, or, just `JSON_COMPACT()`.

But also, this is my thought about it:

In my opinion it should keep the "json-ness" or whenever `JSON_OBJECT` uses that "literal string" it should check whether it's a valid json and treat it like that?     That would make it way more intuitive.